# Why does setPreferredSize() sometimes take precedent over setMinimumSize()?

Tags: java, swing

I had an error yesterday where I added a `JTable` and a `JPanel` (with a `JButton` in it) to a `JScrollPane`. The `JButton` was fixed to the bottom of the table, and it added a row to the `JTable` when clicked.

The problem was if the table ever got bigger than the `JScrollPane`, it would only allow you to scroll to the bottom of the `JTable`; you couldn't get to the `JButton` anymore. Today, I made an MCVE to try and get help, but first I monkeyed with it a bit more and ended up fixing my problem, but in a way that left me with more questions than answers... Here's the MCVE I had prepared:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MCVE extends JFrame{

    private JButton addRow;
    private MCVEModel tableModel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane pane;
    private JPanel scrollPanel, panel;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MCVE();
    }

    public MCVE() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize () {
        this.setTitle("Halp");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 300);
        this.setResizable(false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        /** The JPanel everything is put into **/
        scrollPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(scrollPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        /** The JScrollPane we're using **/
        pane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

        /** The button which keeps getting cut off.... **/
        addRow = new JButton("...");
        addRow.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addRow.setMnemonic('R');
        addRow.setFocusable(false);
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addNewRow();
            }
        });

        /** I wrap the button into this panel so I can affix it to the left **/
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 20));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        addRow.setBounds(0, 0, 35, 15);
        panel.add(addRow);

        /** Faking some data to get the table to populate **/
        ArrayList<List<String>> allData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> fakeData = new ArrayList<String>();
        fakeData.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                  new String[]{"this", "is", "just", "sample", "data"}));
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            allData.add(fakeData);

        List<String> columnNames = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"", "", "", "", ""});
        tableModel = new MCVEModel(columnNames, allData);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(tableModel);

        /** Adding it all together **/
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        scrollPanel.add(table);
        scrollPanel.add(panel);
        mainPanel.add(pane, c);
        this.add(mainPanel);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addNewRow () {
        tableModel.addRow(tableModel.getRowCount(), 
                new String[]{"true", "", "", "false", "false"});
        tableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(
                tableModel.getRowCount(), tableModel.getRowCount());
    }
} 
/** 
 * Just here to keep things compilable. Seriously cut back for the MCVE, 
 * but still replicates the problem without any errors.
 * Nothing below here should be relevant to the issue. 
 */
class MCVEModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6598574844380686148L;
    private List<String> columnNames;
    private List<List<String>> values;

    public MCVEModel (List<String> columnNames, List<List<String>> strings) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.values = strings;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return values == null || values.size() == 0 ? 0 : values.get(0).size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames.get(col);
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return values.get(col).get(row);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return String.class;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        values.get(col).set(row, (String) value);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
            values.get(i).remove(row);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

    public void addRow(int row, String[] strings) {
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
            values.get(i).add(row, strings[i]);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }
}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 20));
```

More precisely, it's with the word "Minimum". By changing this to:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 20));
```

I got exactly the functionality I needed. Now when the table gets too large for the `JScrollPanel`, we're still able to scroll down and see the `JButton`; it's no longer cut off.

I'm assuming this means the `JPanel`'s parent didn't honor its minimum dimensions, but that it did honor its preferred dimensions. Why is this? I had thought `setPreferredSize()`, `setMinimumSize()`, and `setMaximumSize()` interacted like, "I'd prefer to be this big, but no matter what I can't be smaller than my minimum or larger than my maximum," but it seems this isn't the case. I know none of these methods should be used too frequently, but when should I use `setMinimumSize()` over `setPreferredSize()` or vice versa?

Comment: Don't use a null layout or setPreferredSize(). It is the job of a layout manager to dynamically determine the preferred size of the panel. Don't use `fireTableRowsInserted`. It is the job of your table model to invoke that method which it does so there is no need to do it twice.

Comment: I'll concede the `fireTableRowsInserted`, since the code runs identically without it. However, I couldn't get the `JButton` to have this behavior with any of Java's layout managers, and if I wrote a new one it would behave identically to `BoxLayout` except for this one button. It made more sense to me to wrap the button in a `JPanel` that I had complete control over, then put that panel in the `JScrollPane` so I wouldn't have to upset my current layout manager. Is there another way to get my JButton to act like it does without the use of a null layout and/or 'setPreferredSize()?'

Comment: `I couldn't get the JButton to have this behavior` - what behaviour? There is no need for the extra panel. You just add the table and the button to the panel using the BoxLayout and everything will work fine. You only get problems when you start using a null layout or play with the getPreferredSize() method. If you follow this advice then scrolling will work properly.

Comment: `Why does setPreferredSize() sometimes take precedent over setMinimumSize()?` - the basic answer is the minimum/preferred/maximum sizes are only suggestions. Each layout manager can use whatever information is wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is this line:

```
scrollPanel.add(panel);
```

So, `scrollPanel` will contain this panel. Then, `JScrollPane` honors the `preferredSize`-s. Which makes sense, since its purpose is, by using the scroll bars, to make enough room for the contained components. In other words, `JScrollPane` -s impementation ignores the `minimumSize`-s.

**Update:**

From an other angle, `JScrollPane` -s source code checks the `preferredSize` of its children, but not the `minimumSize`. There's no deep philosophy here, `JScrollPane` is implemented this way.

Comment: So why doesn't setMinimumSize ensure that the component is at least the minimum size? That's what the OP is asking and I don't see you answering that question.

Comment: I wrote, scrollPanel honors the `preferredSize`-s. That's it. It ignores the `miniumumSize`. The reason for this is the java source code :)